# Node.js signal handler not working (only run first line)

Tags: node.js

I try to build an event listener to listen to signal events.

```js
process.on('SIGINT', ExitHandler);
process.on('SIGTERM', ExitHandler);
process.on('SIGQUIT', ExitHandler);

async function ExitHandler() {
    console.log('ctrl+c');
    await writeFile('./config/user.json', JSON.stringify(config));
}
```

Contents in the config variable:

```json
{
  '984620726436921364': { SaveAllImage: { convert: false }, Screenshot: { format: 'webp' } }
}
```

The actual content of the user.json file after the end:
(This is the file generated when the file does not exist)

```json
{}
```

#### More info:

npm: 9.1.3
pnpm: 7.25.0
node.js: 19.4.0
os: Windows 11 25276.1000

#### Expected result:

When pressing ctrl+c in the terminal

Save config to config/user.json

#### What actually happened:

not storing anything

Only print "ctrl+c" in the terminal

Comment: You cannot execute async function inside an exit handler. Replace it with `writeFileSync()`

Comment: I tried, sorry I didn't say it.